# How to get name of alias that invoked bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, alias

`$0` expands to the name of the shell script.

```
$ cat ./sample-script
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
$ chmod 700 ./sample-script
$ ./sample-script
./sample-script
```

If the shell script is invoked via a symbolic link, `$0` expands to its name:

```
$ ln -s ./sample-script symlinked-script
$ ./symlinked-script
./symlinked-script
```

How could I get the name of an alias? Here `$0' expands again to the filename:

```
$ alias aliased-script=./sample-script
$ aliased-script
./sample-script
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you already know this, but for the record the answer is: *you need cooperation by the code implementing the alias.*

```
alternate_name () {
  MY_ALIAS_WAS=alternate_name real_name "$@"
}
```

or, if you really want to use the superseded alias syntax:

```
alias alternate_name="MY_ALIAS_WAS=alternate_name real_name"
```

...and then...

```
$ cat ~/bin/real_name
#!/bin/sh
echo $0, I was $MY_ALIAS_WAS, "$@"
```

Comment: But that's not an alias anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are right: I've been using aliases that way since ages. Just didn't think about it, until you reminded me! :-)

Answer (score 13):

Aliases are pretty dumb, according to [the man page](http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html)

> ...Aliases are expanded when a command is read, not when it is executed...

so since bash is basically just replacing a string with another string and then executing it, there's no way for the command to know what was expanded in the alias.

Comment: +1 for a quick, technically correct answer including link and quote. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I looked for this in the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide under Internal Variables](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) and there's no reference there either. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

bash does not make this available. This is why symlinks are used to invoke multiplex commands, and not aliases.